# Xbox One controller charge, where can i see it's charge level/amount?

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

My question is what can i press to see the XBOX ONE controllers charge?
i don't see it anywhere on the dashboard and i find myself charging every night or so which becomes a pain after a while. At first i was using the controller with regular batteries so i figured maybe it will show up when i purchase a rechargeble battery kit. Now that i have one i still dont see it.

Im not 100% sure where to find it.

On the PS4 for example, when you hold the "guide" or middle "PS" button, you see how much charge the battery has. Im looking for something similar.

Any ideas as to where this is shown?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

At this very point in writing the answer you cant tell what your battery life is, but come the February [System update](http://www.totalxbox.com/70715/next-xbox-one-update-revealed-release-date-screenshot-and-details/) it will be on the bottom right corner of the home screen.

Comment: Please update your answer with more recent information! ;)

Answer (score 0):

This information is not available to the user.

There are [suggestions](http://www.videogamer.com/news/microsoft_listening_to_xbox_one_user_complaints.html) that it may be added in a future update, but nothing has been confirmed.